# If statement always returning true in django

Tags: python, django, database, forms, if-statement

I have a problem with my if statement, because it is always returning True.

I have a form where the user can change his profile information. Now I want when he tries to enter an email address that already exists to display an error message, but also when he does not change his current email address, but he changes his name, for example, I want that only the name gets changed. The code I use is:

```
def profil_update(request, slug=None):

    instance = get_object_or_404(Guest, slug=slug)
    form = UpdateGuestProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        print (str(request.POST['email'] == instance.email))

        if not request.POST['email'] == instance.email and Guest.objects.filter(email = request.POST['email']).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'That email address is already taken.', extra_tags='email_exists')
        else:
            instance = form.save(commit = False)
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, "Success", extra_tags='profile_updated')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

    context = {
        "guest": instance,
        "form": form
    }

    return render(request, "base_profile_guest.html", context)
```

So, I think that the problem is because "request.POST['email'] == instance.get_email()" is ALWAYS TRUE. I tried everything and it is always true. Even if email addresses are not equal it is always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to do this in your view unless this is simply a learning exercise, you can just set this on the models to enforce unique emails:

```
 Guest(models.Model):

      ....
      email = models.EmailField(..., unique=True, ...)
      ....
```

Comment: Yes I did that now, and it is working, but it is not displaying a message to the user why it can not save his changes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, thanks to Slayer. Here is what I did:

```
def profil_update(request, slug=None):

    instance = get_object_or_404(Guest, slug=slug)
    form = UpdateGuestProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit = False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "Success", extra_tags='profile_updated')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Email address alredy exists.', extra_tags='email_exists')
    context = {
        "guest": instance,
        "form": form
    }

    return render(request, "base_profile_guest.html", context)
```

So, I added "unique = True" to my model data, as Slayer said. And if form is not valid, I just write a error message. The answer was there all the time I just could not is it, my mistake.